# Haskell From First Principles Ch5, Ex 7,8

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm new to Haskell and reading [Haskell from first principles](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/25587599-haskell-programming-from-first-principles).

right now I'm on chapter 5.
while solving its exercises, specifically 7,8 I could not understand why I'm not coming up with right answer

so here is the question

u can find questions and solutions [here](https://github.com/mvaldesdeleon/haskell-book/blob/master/ch05/exerises.md#type-arguments)

> If the type of kessel is (Ord a, Num b) => a -> b -> a, then the type
> of kessel 1 2 is:
>
> 1. Integer
> 2. Int
> 3. a
> 4. (Num a, Ord a) => a
> 5. Ord a => a
> 6. Num a => a

I think its answer is `5. Ord a => a`, bcs its one of its possible implementation which I have come up with is to completely ignore parameter `b`

like this

```
kessel ::(Ord a, Num b) => a -> b -> a
kessel a b = a
--if u have any other implementation Please share
```

since Its completely ignoring `b` it should not effect the type of `a` but still ghci show its type is

```
:t kessel 1 2       
kessel 1 2 :: (Ord a, Num a) => a
```

What I'm missing ?
same goes with Q:8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Num b` is a red herring. The `Num a` constraint is because you passed a numeric literal for the `a` type, and those require the `Num` typeclass. Try `:t kessel [] 2` to see it go away.

Comment: Thanks for your quick ans yes by pass kessel [] 2 it did go away and Num b is false signal
but still I did not understand why it is (Num a, Ord a) ?
does b is effecting on a ? and why
question is what I'm missing from picture

Comment: "The Num a constraint is because you passed a numeric literal for the a type, and those require the Num typeclass"

then why it go away when we pass [] ?

Comment: @hanan A numeric literal has type `Num a => a` (note the constraint `Num a`), while `[]` has type `[a]`, with no additional constraints. In your example, `kessel` also requires `a` to be `Ord`, and on top of that we add the `Num` because we used a numeric literal. Result: `(Num a, Ord a) => a`.

Comment: Thanks now I understand it